# Find index of item with duplicates

Tags: python, list

I have a list which has many duplicates in, how can I find the index of all the duplicates in the array. So basically I search for a data item and if it has duplicates. It prints out the indexes of where the item is found, including where the duplicates are

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the items in the list are hashable, you could use them as keys in a dict:

```
import collections

somelist = list('ABRACADABRA')
dups = collections.defaultdict(list)
for index, item in enumerate(somelist):
    dups[item].append(index)
print(dups)
```

yields

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'A': [0, 3, 5, 7, 10], 'R': [2, 9], 'B': [1, 8], 'C': [4], 'D': [6]})
```

---

If the items are not hashable (such as a list), then the next best solution is to define a `key` function (if possible) which maps each item to a unique hashable object (such as a tuple):

```
def key(item):
    return something_hashable
for index, item in enumerate(somelist):
    dups[key(item)].append(index)
```

---

If no such `key` can be found, you'd have to store the seen items in a list, and test for duplicates by testing equality with each item in the list of seen objects. This is O(n**2).

```
# Don't use this unless somelist contains unhashable items
import collections
somelist = list('ABRACADABRA')
seen = []
dups = collections.defaultdict(list)
for i, item in enumerate(somelist):
    for j, orig in enumerate(seen):
        if item == orig:
            dups[j].append(i)
            break
    else:
        seen.append(item)
print([(seen[key], val) for key, val in dups.iteritems()])
```

yields

```
[('A', [3, 5, 7, 10]), ('B', [8]), ('R', [9])]
```

Comment: This would be the most efficient way to do it, if you were really crazy you could also keep a `set` of which keys are actually duplicates, however this won't probably be needed, traversing the `dict`at the end should be enough.

Comment: @jamylak. Sets would need to test membership which would require O(n) traversal in the worst case if not found. If implemented as a linked list.

Comment: @Dave I have never heard of a `set` that requires O(n) membership checks

Comment: @Dave of course that isn't considering hash collisions. I'm talking about amortized time here, O(n) will never practically happen for sets

Comment: @jamylak, what if the item that you are testing membership for in the set does not exist. You would have traversed the entire linked list to find that out. (If you implement a set as a linked list). I think we're talking about different underlying data structures. https://gist.github.com/djohnsonm/5301054

Comment: @Dave Yes we are talking about different things. I would not want to implement a set as a linked list, I'm talking about hash tables

Comment: @jamylak yes, I guess its all dependent on your hash function then since a hash table is just an array of linked lists. A bad hash could in theory still give you O(n)

Comment: We use big-oh notation to evaluate in the worst case. You should read the source for python's dict. "But it's extremely unlikely hash codes will follow a 5*j+1 recurrence by accident, and certain that consecutive hash codes do not." While it's "extremely" unlikely double-hashing will result in anything less than O(1), there is still a worst case...  http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/dictobject.c

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def get_duplicate_indexes(li):
    retval = {}
    for i, x in enumerate(li):
        if x not in retval:
            retval[x] = []
        retval[x].append(i)
    return retval
```

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> temp = {}
>>> def print_dupes(a):
...     for i,j in enumerate(a):
...             temp[j] = 0
...     for i,j in enumerate(a):
...             temp[j] += 1
...     for i,j in enumerate(a):
...             if temp[j] > 1:
...                     print i
...
>>> print_dupes([1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3])
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
>>> print_dupes([1,1,1,2,2,2,3])
0
1
2
3
4
5
>>> print_dupes([1,1,1,2,3])
0
1
2
```

Comment: you are not printing the indexes of the first duplicates found. eg. both of the `1s`

Comment: @jamylak ok, check it now. O(n)

Comment: You should post all of your code, `temp` isn't ever defined in this

Comment: @jamylak Ok it's fixed. You can remove your -1.

Comment: The problem was that the hash table needed to be initialized with values.