# Find indices of duplicated rows in python ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, data-science

I coded the for loop to enumerate a multidimensional ndarray containing n rows of 28x28 pixel values.

I am looking for the index of each row that is duplicated and the indices of the duplicates without redundancies.

I found this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15787582/find-index-of-item-with-duplicates) (thanks unutbu) and modified it to read the ndarray, it works 70% of the time, however 30% of the time it is identifying the wrong images as duplicates.

How can it be improved to detect the correct rows?

```
def overlap_same(arr):
seen = []
dups = collections.defaultdict(list)
for i, item in enumerate(arr):
    for j, orig in enumerate(seen):
        if np.array_equal(item, orig):
            dups[j].append(i)
            break
    else:
        seen.append(item)
return dups
```

e.g. return overlap_same(train) returns:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {34: [1388], 35: [1815], 583: [3045], 3208:
[4426], 626: [824], 507: [4438], 188: [338, 431, 540, 757, 765, 806,
808, 834, 882, 1515, 1539, 1715, 1725, 1789, 1841, 2038, 2081, 2165,
2170, 2300, 2455, 2683, 2733, 2957, 3290, 3293, 3311, 3373, 3446, 3542,
3565, 3890, 4110, 4197, 4206, 4364, 4371, 4734, 4851]})
```

plotting some samples of the correct case on matplotlib gives:

```
fig = plt.figure()
a=fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
plt.imshow(train[35])
a.set_title('train[35]')
a=fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)
plt.imshow(train[1815])
a.set_title('train[1815]')
plt.show
```

[image: train data 35 vs 1815]

which is correct

However:

```
fig = plt.figure()
a=fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
plt.imshow(train[3208])
a.set_title('train[3208]')
a=fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)
plt.imshow(train[4426])
a.set_title('train[4426]')
plt.show
```

[image]

is incorrect as they do not match

Sample data (train[:3])

```
array([[[-0.5       , -0.5       , -0.5       , ...,  0.48823529,
      0.5       ,  0.17058824],
    [-0.5       , -0.5       , -0.5       , ...,  0.48823529,
      0.5       , -0.0372549 ],
    [-0.5       , -0.5       , -0.5       , ...,  0.5       ,
      0.47647059, -0.24509804],
    ..., 
    [-0.49215686,  0.34705883,  0.5       , ..., -0.5       ,
     -0.5       , -0.5       ],
    [-0.31176472,  0.44901961,  0.5       , ..., -0.5       ,
     -0.5       , -0.5       ],
    [-0.11176471,  0.5       ,  0.49215686, ..., -0.5       ,
     -0.5       , -0.5       ]],

   [[-0.24509804,  0.2764706 ,  0.5       , ...,  0.5       ,
      0.25294119, -0.36666667],
    [-0.5       , -0.47254902, -0.02941176, ...,  0.20196079,
     -0.46862745, -0.5       ],
    [-0.49215686, -0.5       , -0.5       , ..., -0.47647059,
     -0.5       , -0.49607843],
    ..., 
    [-0.49215686, -0.49607843, -0.5       , ..., -0.5       ,
     -0.5       , -0.49215686],
    [-0.5       , -0.5       , -0.26862746, ...,  0.13137256,
     -0.46470588, -0.5       ],
    [-0.30000001,  0.11960784,  0.48823529, ...,  0.5       ,
      0.28431374, -0.24117647]],

   [[-0.5       , -0.5       , -0.5       , ..., -0.5       ,
     -0.5       , -0.5       ],
    [-0.5       , -0.5       , -0.5       , ..., -0.5       ,
     -0.5       , -0.5       ],
    [-0.5       , -0.5       , -0.5       , ..., -0.5       ,
     -0.5       , -0.5       ],
    ..., 
    [-0.5       , -0.5       , -0.5       , ...,  0.48431373,
      0.5       ,  0.31568629],
    [-0.5       , -0.49215686, -0.5       , ...,  0.49215686,
      0.5       ,  0.04901961],
    [-0.5       , -0.5       , -0.5       , ...,  0.04117647,
     -0.17450981, -0.45686275]]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Could you add a minimal representative sample case and the expected output?

Comment: Sure, I'll add one right away!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package has a lot of functionality to solve these type of problems efficiently.

For instance, (unlike numpy's builtin unique) this will find your unique images:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
unique_training_images = npi.unique(train)
```

Or if you want to find all the indices of each unique group, you can use:

```
indices = npi.group_by(train).split(np.arange(len(train)))
```

Note that these functions do not have quadratic time complexity, like in your original post, and are fully vectorized, and thus in all likelihood a lot more efficient. Also, unlike pandas it does not have a preferred data format, and is fully nd-array capable, so acting on arrays with shape [n_images, 28, 28] 'just works'.

Comment: Cheers, I'll try this out

Comment: Thanks a lot, it returns the indices of the duplicates, actually just realised everything is grouped.

Comment: Yeah I figured that output most closely resembles the one you are after; but what the most convenient format is depends of course on the details of subsequent steps. Does this serve your purposes?

Comment: Yeah it does, just tested the other one out and it returns multiple incorrect values, the numpy indexed returns the correct ones, there are still some missed out but its more accurate. I really appreciate it!

Comment: What do you mean by missed out? Could that be related to floating point errors? Try using numpy.round with a reduced number of decimals on your input data, in that case.

Comment: Yeah that sorted it out, it works better with an increased amount of decimals

Comment: Is there a function in npi I could use to get the index of the duplicated row in one array and the indices of the duplicates of a separate array? For example to find duplicates of training data located in testing data

Comment: indices is a jagged array; you could split each array into a head and tail to get the behavior you describe, no? or are you talking about finding the indices of the elements of one array in another? if so, take a look at the npi.indices function.